# Shouldn't [boxes] be [gnome-boxes]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I untagged the one and only question with the newly created [gnome-boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-boxes) tag with the usual destructive intent.

Someone in chat told me I shouldn't have done that, and someone else noticed that all the questions we have about GNOME Boxes are tagged [boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boxes)

[Here they are, look.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boxes)

A cursory glance took in [one post there that does not belong](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841706/all-fonts-on-xubuntu-are-now-boxes-everything-is-illegible-help) - it's just randomly about boxes of some kind.

Since [boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boxes) is a vague tag with the potential to be used inconsistently, shouldn't these questions be retagged, well, [gnome-boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-boxes)?

Comment: That one post that doesn't belong talks about fonts not being properly decoded, so characters show up as squares ( or in their words - boxes ), so that one definitely is tagged incorrectly as far as gnome-boxes go, which is for virtualization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with you that [gnome-boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-boxes) makes more sense than [boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boxes).

Questions with both [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome) and [boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boxes) as tags probably can be retagged with just [gnome-boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-boxes).

There are also [some posts mentioning "gnome boxes"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22gnome%20boxes%22%20is%3Aq) and we should check which of those questions need this new tag and add them where necessary.

And we also need a shiny new tag wiki for the new tag. :)

Comment: :) It's done, although the wiki could use some work

Answer (score -4):

I think Boxes is OK since this is a site for **Ubuntu** and the Application is called this way, gnome-boxes is the name of the software package. In everyday use the user will have to remind is called *Boxes* to launch it.

Comment: GNOME Terminal is also called "Terminal". That'd be a fun tag. And the actual command is, as with `gnome-terminal`, `gnome-boxes`

Comment: @muru I get your point but it is just related to invoking from commands, I'm on launching applications

Comment: are you saying typing GNOME Boxes in the dash doesn't show the app?

Comment: No, but boxes works when Gnome boxes may be an user friendly feature. As per the .desktop entry I think Boxes is the way to launch it from the dash

Comment: it's for the same reason that GNOME Terminal also works, they know that when using a generic word like boxes or terminal, somebody else may also use the same word for a different application.

Comment: I haven't got the need of having more than one terminal, let's wait until this generic names like Windows and Photoshop disappear for ambiguity to disappear. Happy llamas

Comment: @userDepth You may not, but users of Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Kubuntu, etc, all have different terminal applications.